# API GET request getting different result if in main versus python test file

Tags: python, rest

I am still learning on how to code, and I am now at the stage of doing some API.

**[CONTEXT]**

In my current project, what I am trying to achieve is:

- read IATA airport code from a google spreadsheet (all OK with that)
- send a GET request to an API (endpoint: https://api.tequila.kiwi.com) with json parameters to get cheapest flight from tomorrow up to 6 months ahead.

**[ISSUE]**

Main file is not getting the exact same result than a test file with same parameters.

**Source:**
(Did not include APIKEY/HEADERS as I get a response 200 OK), neither the import.

```
tomorrow = (datetime.today() + timedelta(1)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
six_months_date = (datetime.today() + timedelta(weeks=24)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

parameter_WE = {
    "fly_from": "SIN",
    "fly_to": "",
    "date_from": tomorrow,
    "date_to": six_months_date,
    "nights_in_dst_from": 2,
    "nights_in_dst_to": 2,
    "max_fly_duration": 7,
    "flight_type": "round",
    "adults": 1,
    "selected_cabins": "M",
    "adult_hold_bag": "1",
    "partner_market": "sg",
    "curr": "SGD",
    "max_stopovers": 0,
    "vehicle_type": "aircraft",
    "limit": 10,
    "fly_days": "5",
    "dtime_from": "19:00",
    "ret_dtime_from": "16:00"
}

def main(element: list):
list_result = []
# element is a list [city, IATAcode, cost] below is the simplified code for the understanding
if element[1] == "HKT":
   parameter_WE["fly_to"] = element[1]
   response = requests.get(url=URL_BOOKING, headers=self.header_booking, params=parameter_WE)

if response.json()["data"]:
   data = response.json()["data"][0]
   # print(data)
   dict_data = {
                    "to": data["flyTo"],
                    "price": round(data["fare"]["adults"]),
                    "datefrom": f'{data["local_departure"].split("T")[0]}'+f' - {data["local_departure"].split("T")[1].split(".")[0][:-3]}',
                    "dateto": f'{data["route"][1]["local_departure"].split("T")[0]}'+f' - {data["route"][1]["local_departure"].split("T")[1].split(".")[0][:-3]}',
                    "airlinefrom": data["route"][0]["airline"],
                    "airlinereturn": data["route"][1]["airline"],
                }
 list_result.append(dict_data)

return list_result
```

The result I am getting is empty if the json parameter `"ret_dtime_from": "16:00"` stays as is...
(I did not mention above the "else" statement that return a list with "not found" and working perfectly that will be filled into the GSpreadsheet)

If I remove it, I get a flight departure dd/mm/yyyy 03/02/2023 to 05/02/2023 with a time of departure from HKT to SIN at 09:00AM

However, if I create a completely single test file, the code below gives me a json with data, with a flight departure dd/mm/yyyy 03/02/2023 to 05/02/2023 with a time of departure from HKT to SIN at 16:15

```
tomorrow = (datetime.today() + timedelta(1)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
six_months_date = (datetime.today() + timedelta(weeks=24)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
header_booking = {
    "accept": "application / json",
    "apikey": KEY_BOOKING
}

parameter_WE = {
    "fly_from": "SIN",
    "fly_to": "HKT",
    "date_from": "03/02/2023",
    "date_to": "05/02/2023",
    "nights_in_dst_from": 2,
    "nights_in_dst_to": 2,
    "max_fly_duration": 7,
    "flight_type": "round",
    "adults": 1,
    "selected_cabins": "M",
    "adult_hold_bag": "1",
    "partner_market": "sg",
    "curr": "SGD",
    "max_stopovers": 0,
    "vehicle_type": "aircraft",
    "limit": 10,
    "fly_days": "5",
    "dtime_from": "19:00",
    "ret_dtime_from": "16:00"
}

response = requests.get(url=URL_BOOKING, headers=header_booking, params=parameter_WE)
return response.text
```

I can not point out what is wrong in my code.

Thanks

Comment: arg ... after checking directly the API via the portal, I found out that I needed to put the limit to 500 (number of airlines checked)

SOLVED

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED by changing limit
:)

Silly me

Adding a few characters to make it minimum